# Symfony: routing with subdomain --> 404 error

Tags: php, symfony, routes, subdomain

I'm new with Symfony (5.3) and i'm trying to use the EasyAdmin^3 package and its controller.

```
class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin", name="admin")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        //return parent::index();
        $routeBuilder = $this->get(AdminUrlGenerator::class);
        $url = $routeBuilder->setController(BookCrudController::class)->generateUrl();
        return $this->redirect($url);
    }

    public function configureDashboard(): Dashboard
    {
     ...
    }
    ....
```

In security.yaml, there is no access control:

```
access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I tried on my computer with

```
>symfony server:start -d
>symfony open:local
```

The URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin works

But on my server https://subdomain.domain.com/admin it doesn't work (error 404).
But the route is configuring:

```
>php bin/console debug:router
admin                      ANY      ANY      ANY                             /admin
```

Comment: Unless you did something extra special, Symfony doesn’t care about domains, subdomains, IPs or even ports, so your problem is probably elsewhere. Do you have debug enabled on the server?

Answer (score 1):

the URL to wasn't redirected to /public/
I added in / directory .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

and added .htaccess in /public/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

And then the /admin was forbidden, then I added in DashboardController file / function configureDashboard()

```
return Dashboard::new()
          ->disableUrlSignatures()
          ...
```